One button with two actions on HTML
I made a button in HTML and when I clicked it the first action worked but the second one didn't. I want the same button to replace the text with new text after the second click.
<body>
        <button onclick=dosomething(); onclick=dosomething2() style="background-color:
        aquamarine;color:purple;
        font-size:40px;border-radius:100px;">Click Me!</button>

        <p style="color:red;font-size:80px;" id="test"></p>
        <script>
            function dosomething(){
                document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "Why did you do what it said >:("
            }
        </script>
        <script>
            function dosomething2(){
                document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "Stop it >:("
            }
        </script>
</body>


What exactly are you trying to accomplish?  Setting the same element to two different values will result in setting it to the second value.  What was the purpose of the first?

If you want the first click to change the text to "Why did you do what it said >:(" and a second click to change that text to "Stop it >:(", then just create one function, and count the clicks with a variable

Also, don't use innerHTML when the string you are working with doesn't contain any HTML as innerHTML has security and performance implications. Use .textContent instead.

And, there's no need to put each function inside of its own script element. Just create one script, place it just prior to the closing body tag and put all your JS within that one script.

Stop using inline event listeners
Inline event listeners are an outdated piece of technology superseded by addEventListener.
With addEventListener you can add multiple click listeners and perform multiple functions. It also keeps your JS separate from your HTML.
The example below demonstrates how one would add multiple click listeners to a single element.


const button = document.querySelector('button');

function dosomething() {
  document.getElementById("first").textContent = "Why did you do what it said >:("
}

function dosomething2() {
  document.getElementById("second").textContent = "Stop it >:("
}

button.addEventListener('click', dosomething);
button.addEventListener('click', dosomething2);
<button style="background-color: aquamarine; color:purple; font-size:40px;border-radius:100px;">Click Me!</button>

<p style="color:red;font-size:80px;" id="first"></p>
<p style="color:red;font-size:80px;" id="second"></p>




You cannot set several attributes to an HTML element with the same name, only the first is counted. So 2 onclicks wouldn't work here.
Since you a novice for learning purposes you could use the same approach with onclick but overwrite the function on the first click with a new function that sets the second text.
That's because a function is first-class and can be assigned to a variable too.
Here you can see also how a closure works with the test variable. Also arrow functions are encountered as well const/let. A nice example to learn something new in JS.


<button onclick="doSomething()" style="background-color:
aquamarine;color:purple;
font-size:40px;border-radius:100px;">Click Me!</button>

<p style="color:red;font-size:80px;" id="test"></p>
<script>
    let doSomething = () => {
      const test = document.getElementById("test");
      test.innerHTML = "Why did you do what it said >:(";
      doSomething = () => test.innerHTML = "Stop it >:(";
    };
</script>




You should explain how your answer actually works

@j08691 added an explanation


Only the first instance of the onclick attribute will be treated. If you want to change what the action being performed is, you will need an external method of tracking.
<body>
  <button onclick="dosomething();" style="background-color:aquamarine;color:purple;font-size:40px;border-radius:100px;">Click Me!</button>
  <p style="color:red;font-size:80px;" id="test"></p>
  <script>
    // Save how many times the button has been clicked
    let clicks = 0;

    // Save time by prefetching the element to avoid looking for it multiple times
    const testElement = document.getElementById("test");

    function dosomething() {
      clicks++;
      switch(clicks) {
        case 1:
          testElement.innerHTML = "Why did you do what it said >:(";
          break;
        case 2:
          testElement.innerHTML = "Stop it >:(";
          break;
        default:
          // Any further clicking will fall here. Delete me if unneeded
          testElement.innerHTML = "Bork bork bork etc...";
          break;
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>


Just like the other answer, albeit in a different way, this will not product the desired result. You'll never see the text change from dosomething() since it will immediately be overridden by dosomething2

The thing though is that the text would change to the second function immediately, I want it to change to the second function after the button is clicked again.

Oh, my bad. The question wasn't too clear about that. I'll edit the answer to adjust.

The OP doesn't want to change the text after a delay, they want it to change after they click. First click, change text to one thing. Second click, change text to something else.

No problem, will do complete rewrite. If possible, someone should suggest edits on the question to clarify as much, as it's not clear what the intentions are.

As others have said, attributes can only be used once per instance of an element, so instead of having onclick twice on one button, you can simply have one onclick that causes two functions to run, like this:
<button type="button" onclick="func1();func2()"></button>

Beyond that though, you don't need separate script elements for each function, they can be combined into one script.
Additionally, don't use innerHTML when the string you are working with doesn't contain any HTML as innerHTML has security and performance implications. Use textContent instead.


<body>
        <button onclick="dosomething();onclick=dosomething2()" style="background-color:
        aquamarine;color:purple;
        font-size:40px;border-radius:100px;">Click Me!</button>

        <p style="color:red;font-size:80px;" id="test"></p>
        <script>
            // Just get references to elements once, not each time the function runs
            const test = document.getElementById("test");
            function dosomething(){
                console.log("Why did you do what it said >:(");
            }
            function dosomething2(){
                test.textContent = "Stop it >:("
            }
        </script>
</body>



And finally, you really should avoid inline event handlers, like onclick or inline styles in the first place and instead, you should use the modern DOM API of .addEventListener() in JavaScript to do your event binding. See comments below:


<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test Page</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
    /* Use CSS classes instead of inline styles */
    button {
      background-color: aquamarine;
      color:purple;
      font-size:40px;
      border-radius:100px;
    }
    p {
      color:red;
      font-size:80px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <button>Click Me!</button>
  <p id="test"></p>
  <script>
    // Just get references to elements once, not each time the function runs
    const test = document.getElementById("test");
    
    // Use the modern approach to event binding.
    // For multiple event handlers, just repeat as shown here:
    document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", dosomething);
    document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", dosomething2);    
    
    function dosomething(){
      console.log("Why did you do what it said >:(");
    }
   function dosomething2(){
      test.textContent = "Stop it >:("
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>




You can run 2 actions from one button by creating 1 function with all functions you need to run in it.  You can modify your code like this:
<body>
    <button onclick=doEverything();style="background-color:
    aquamarine;color:purple;
    font-size:40px;border-radius:100px;">Click Me!</button>

    <p style="color:red;font-size:80px;" id="test"></p>
    <script>
        function dosomething(){
            document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "Why did you do what it said >:("
        }
        function dosomething2(){
            document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "Stop it >:("
        }
       function doEverything(){
   dosomething();
   dosomething2();
  }
    </script>


Did you test your code? The functions would be executed so quickly that you'd never see the first change

try
<body>
    <button onclick="dosomething()"
        style="background-color: aquamarine; color: purple; font-size: 40px; border-radius: 100px;">Click Me!</button>
    <p style="color: red; font-size: 80px;" id="test"></p>
    <script>
        function dosomething2() {
            document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "Stop it >:("
        }
        function dosomething() {
            document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "Why did you do what it said >:("
            document.querySelector("button").onclick = dosomething2
        }
    </script>
</body>

Change the onclick of the button right after using dosomething.
